# Android: Stretching ImageView with background

Tags: android, layout

I have a landscape layout that features a vertical LinearLayout of buttons on the left side of the screen and a user-defined picture on the right of the screen.  The design I'm working from calls for a double-stroke border around it, which I implemented by creating a rectangular shape background with the border being the outer color and the background of the shape being the inner color.  I then just put some padding around the picture, and you get the double-stroke border.  The problem is expanding the picture to fill the space in the layout.  I don't know the dimensions of the picture, since it is user defined, and I'd like it to expand to exactly fill either dimension while preserving the aspect ratio.  Setting fill_parent for both width and height does that, but it also expands the background all the way to completely fill the cell, resulting in a sort of letter boxing effect.  Is there any way, short of just adjusting the size of the view after layout, of getting this to only expand the view as much as necessary?

Comment: text too long and also screenshot would've helped make things clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got this to work properly, and just ended up adjusting my layout to a different arrangement.